# Do I have to be a relay to use Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I just installed Tor browser and I would like to know if the default configuration is set to be a relay or normal user. And then, just close the browser to disconnect from the Tor network?

Answer (score 1):

Nope when you use the Tor Browser you are only using Tor.  You are not set up as a relay with default configuration.  That would be misleading if the default configuration was to set each user up as a relay.

Comment: Thanks. And how can i sign out from the network once I close the browser? Is it an automatic process?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.